# How do I create a ClaimsIdentity object for Asp.NET MVC 5?

Tags: authentication, ravendb, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, katana

I am working in a .NET MVC 5 application. I do not want to use Entity Framework. I want to authenticate to a RavenDB database. It looks to me that I want to replace the `UserManager` that comes with the Account Controller. I think I can rewrite all the UserManager functions to work with my database, except I don't understand the `ClaimsIdentity` object.

In the `SignInAsync` method, there is a call to `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(...)`. I know it returns a `ClaimsIdentity` object. What I don't know is how to create a ClaimsIdentity object on my own.

I see that it has 4 properties `Actor`, `BootstrapContext`, `Claims` and `Label`. I don't know what these properties are used for, and I don't know how to properly generate them. I assume generating them correctly is important since it is how the authentication cookie is made.

I looked at the explanation of the ClaimsIdentity object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but that didn't really help me understand.

If I could see the code for `CreateIdentityAsync()`, that would probably help.

If I'm going about this all wrong, please let me know. Otherwise, if someone could point me toward how to generate the ClaimsIdentity object, that would be helpful.

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity
{
    Actor = ????,
    BootstrapContext = ?????,
    Claims = ?????,
    Label = ?????
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Perhaps the [following link](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/) can help:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Brock"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "brockallen@gmail.com"));
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

Answer (score 20):

I think you are "going about this all wrong".  The ASP.NET Identity Framework is designed with pluggable persistence in mind.  The correct way to substitute RavenDB for EF is NOT to replace the `UserManager`.  Rather, it is to implement a replacement `UserStore`.  So the line in the `AccountController` that creates the `UserManager` would change from:

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
```

To:

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new RavenDBUserStore<ApplicationUser>/* connection info here*/)))
```

Where the `RavenDBUserStore` would be a class you wrote that implemented `IUserStore`, `IUserPasswordStore` and whatever other *Store interfaces you needed for your particular application.

**This approach avoids you needing to understand and re-implement everything in `UserManager` and ensures that you will be able to take advantage of future improvements to the `UserManager` from MS.**

For more information on how to do this, see the [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) and the example of [Implementing a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider).  You should also check out the code of the [RavenDB.AspNet.Identity Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/) created by [David Boike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10039/david-boike) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407684/268898). The source is  on github at https://github.com/ILMServices/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer to the problem at hand: namely, "how to use a different datastore with Identity 2.0". Reimplementing your own `ClaimsIdentity` without fully understanding how and why is just asking for trouble down the track. +1 for understanding the framework as it's intended to be used

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I came up with. I would love to know if this is the correct way to accomplish this task.

Working in a default MVC5 website, I went to the Account Controller, and found the `SignInAsync()` function. I adjusted it as follows:

```
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        //var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); --> this is where I want to get rid of UserManager
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>{
            new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", user.Name), //user.Name from my database
            new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", user.Id), //user.Id from my database
            new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "MyApplication"),
            new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName) //user.FirstName from my database
        };
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

Keep in mind that this also requires changing the `[HttpPost] Login` function to get the user from my database instead of using the `UserManager.FindAsync()` function.

The LogIn/LogOff parts of the default site seem to work fine after these adjustments. I'll leave this answer here for a while before I accept it in case someone can tell me why I shouldn't do it this way.

Comment: Though the ramifications of people using this approach without fully understanding it do frighten me, others should look into the `ClaimTypes` enum for generating the schema URIs: specifically, `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` which will generate `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"`, et. al.

Comment: Gonna expand on these "ramifications" of this "approach"?

Answer (score 6):

I created a RavenDB implementation for the new ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity and released it as a NuGet package. This might work for you.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/

It's somewhat prerelease but I am using it in a real project.

Here's the [GitHub project](https://github.com/ILMServices/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity) and a [short thread on the RavenDB discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/TwmE8BjDpNY) about it.