# ASP.NET windows authentication with impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I want to enable windows authentication for my ASP.NET intranet application.
For that, I did the below in my `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Windows" >

    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\myusername" password="mypwd" />
</system.web>
```

And I am trying to access the authenticated user name in my web page as

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

It throws an "access denied" error message.

Comment: So do you have to get the Impersonated name there in your web page ?

Comment: no, am not getting any user name here, It  throws me access denied error. When I removed the authorization tag, I could access my page, but not getting the impersonated user .

Comment: Try using `WindowsIdentity.Name` or `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` instead of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: hi, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name works correctly. Thanks for the info. and can I add some roles in UserClaims from SQL table??

Comment: Probably yes. Check my answer.

Comment: If you are after authenticating against active directory on your intranet, then impersonating isn't for you.

Comment: One more question is, why am not getting the logged user by using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
Is there any specific reason??

Comment: Not sure as to why that is not working.I am checking that too. You can try setting the name in cookie and then retrieving it for further use.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `WindowsIdentity.Name` or `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` instead of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

As far as adding roles to `Claim` is concerned, you can add it with the help of some code. These links might help you :

[Creating ClaimIdentity Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391592/how-do-i-create-a-claimsidentity-object-for-asp-net-mvc-5)

[Claim Based Security in C#](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/11/introduction-to-claims-based-security-in-net4-5-with-c-part-1/)

Hope this helps.